# Send keystokes in other applications

Tags: java, processing

I wrote the following "Processing" script using Java's "Robot" class, and it works perfectly fine on Windows and Mac. However, if I open up an application, like a game, the clicks do not work! The game I tried was Battlefield 4. Here is the mouse click code;

```
import processing.serial.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

Serial myPort;
String val;
Robot mouseBot;

void setup(){
  String portName=Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  try {
    mouseBot = new Robot();
  }
  catch(AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

void draw() {
  if(myPort.available()>0)
  {
      if(myPort.read()==1)
        {
          mouseBot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
          mouseBot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, I can click around in native Windows or native OSX, and it works perfectly fine. But ingame, the clicks do not register. Is there another way to send mouse commands so that it can be recognized in other applications? Thanks!

Carpetfizz

Comment: Most games either naively block this kind of behaviour or it's not executed low enough within the OS API for the game to recognise it

Comment: Thanks much, I just tried it in another game (Arma III) and it worked fine. Do you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many games now days have the ability to detect these kind of events. BF for one employees punk buster for example.

Its possible that a Robot simply isn't generating the system events low enough within the given OS's API to allow these events to be recognised within the game